# Are there differences between graphics cards for a workstation and desktop?

Tags: graphics-card, workstation

I bought a 2013 HP Z600 workstation from my workplace in an auction. It does not come with a graphics card. I am thinking of buying one, but I don't want to spend over $80 on it. My question is, can I use regular, every day desktop graphics cards for workstation? Or is it only compatible with special graphics cards/high-end graphics cards?

Thanks.

Comment: It should work with either, but the question of which you need will be determined by your applications. if you use CAD software, you need a workstation graphics card. If not, a graphics card that is sufficient to your apps (do you run big games?) will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with workstations and desktops - they're pretty much the same as far as interfaces go. You can load a regular graphics with the right interface into a workstation.

The *differences* are workstation cards *may* be better at some workloads (which doesn't matter in your case) but there's little stopping you from tossing a spare quadro or fire into a gaming PC or a gaming card into a workstation.

That said, workstations can be a little unusual - I'd check to see if there's a GPU power connector available (you can convert these from a spare molex, or presumably sata power supply), and your PSU may not be compatible with a standard ATX, especially if you're running dual processors.

At the 80 dollar price range, eh, you shouldn't be running into too much trouble with any common PCIe GPU

Answer (score 3):

You can use any graphics card that is compatible with the bus type (PCI, PCIe) of the workstation and with your operating system.

Comment: 2013 ought to be PCIe.. I'd also check for GPU power, if needed.